# detect regions of scanned image using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a C# application to process scanned images. The scanned image contains 12 rectangular subregions as shown below.

Are there any libraries or code samples that can help me to identify the position and dimensions of each region?

[image: sample scanned image]

Help me. I searched a article in codeproject (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265354/Playing-Card-Recognition-Using-AForge-Net-Framewor) have solution that I want. It have 2 projects. First project PlayingCardRecognition, I created files

> TestCard.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace PlayingCardRecognition
{
    public class TestCard
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Bitmap bitmap { get; set; }
        public Point[] point { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> TestCardCollection.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace PlayingCardRecognition
{
    public class TestCardCollection : CollectionBase
    {
        public void Add(TestCard card)
        {
            this.List.Add(card);
        }
    }
}
```

> I changed file **CardRecognizer.cs**, I add a method **ExtractImages** changed from **Recognize** method

```
public TestCardCollection ExtractImages(Bitmap source)
    {
        TestCardCollection col = new TestCardCollection();
        Bitmap temp = source.Clone() as Bitmap; //Clone image to keep original image

        FiltersSequence seq = new FiltersSequence();
        seq.Add(Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709);  //First add  grayScaling filter
        seq.Add(new OtsuThreshold()); //Then add binarization(thresholding) filter
        temp = seq.Apply(source); // Apply filters on source image

        //Extract blobs from image whose size width and height larger than 150
        BlobCounter extractor = new BlobCounter();
        extractor.FilterBlobs = true;
        extractor.MinWidth = extractor.MinHeight = 150;
        extractor.MaxWidth = extractor.MaxHeight = 350;
        extractor.ProcessImage(temp);

        //Will be used transform(extract) cards on source image 
        QuadrilateralTransformation quadTransformer = new QuadrilateralTransformation();

        //Will be used resize(scaling) cards 
        ResizeBilinear resizer = new ResizeBilinear(CardWidth, CardHeight);

        Blob[] blobs = extractor.GetObjectsInformation();

        for (int i = 0; i < blobs.Length; i++)
        {
            Blob blob = blobs[i];
            TestCard card = new TestCard();
            card.name = "" + i;


            List<IntPoint> edgePoints = extractor.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blob);
            //Calculate/Find corners of card on source image from edge points
            List<IntPoint> corners = PointsCloud.FindQuadrilateralCorners(edgePoints);
            if (corners.Count < 4)
                quadTransformer.SourceQuadrilateral = new List<IntPoint>(edgePoints);
            else
                quadTransformer.SourceQuadrilateral = corners; //Set corners for transforming card 
            quadTransformer.AutomaticSizeCalculaton = true;

            Bitmap cardImg = quadTransformer.Apply(source); //Extract(transform) card image

            if (cardImg.Width > cardImg.Height) //If card is positioned horizontally
                cardImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone); //Rotate
            card.bitmap = resizer.Apply(cardImg); //Normalize card size

            IntPoint[] cornerIntPoints = corners.ToArray();

            Point[] corner = new Point[cornerIntPoints.Length];
            for (int z = 0; z < cornerIntPoints.Length; z++)
            {
                corner[z].X = cornerIntPoints[z].X;
                corner[z].Y = cornerIntPoints[z].Y;
            }
            card.point = corner;
            col.Add(card);
        }

        return col;
    }
```

> Second project PlayingCardRecognition_SampleImages I have **test.cs** file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;
using PlayingCardRecognition;

namespace PlayingCardRecognition_SampleImages
{
    public partial class test : Form
    {
        public test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ResizeBilinear resizer = new ResizeBilinear(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            Bitmap bm = Properties.Resources.testtrip;
            pictureBox1.Image = resizer.Apply(bm);

        }
        private CardRecognizer recognizer = new CardRecognizer();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int w = 0;
            TestCardCollection col =  recognizer.ExtractImages(Properties.Resources.testtrip);
            foreach (TestCard card in col)
            {
                PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
                pic.Image = card.bitmap;
                pic.Width = card.bitmap.Width;
                pic.Height = card.bitmap.Height;
                pic.Location = new Point(w, 0);
                pnMain.Controls.Add(pic);
                w += card.bitmap.Width + 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I called **ExtractImages** method, I get 12 images but region wrong
It show like image below. [show image return](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-fxoaERStDvE/UNPfbreQPhI/AAAAAAAAACQ/V-m2v0Zhs88/s912/test8.png)
Why?
my project at [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?m9a9nj7pr8z8ikf)

Thank and sorry for my English.

Comment: This is a massive question.

Comment: Massive, ambiguous, and it looks like you're working on something I wouldn't support. Care to show at least some original research?

Comment: Sorry because my English very bad, thank [GargantuChet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/171012/gargantuchet) has edit my question. I think using aforget.net framework but I not yet have the solution.

Comment: Question really does not deserve 5 downvotes. Yes, question was massive and without any attempted code, but was not useless or senseless.

Answer (score 1):

check out OpenCV, it has a .Net version I think.

basically, you need define what are regions. then use edge to segment them since they are rectangular. Usually, you can use image processing tool (i.e. Matlab image processing toolbox) to test your algorithm and make sure it works, then write C#.

Comment: I learned about OpenCV, but i think it do not help solve my problem.

Comment: openCV is a computer vision library which includes many image processing methods. so you do not need to code everything from scratch. as to your specific question, you will have to do it yourself. it is not a small job if you want it works for all kinds of images.

Comment: Thank [Urlreader](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1357627/urlreader), but i want get images (12 rectangular subregions) in my app, because I need to process each image after I extract from the scaned image so I can not use OpenCV. I has done processed images,my issue now is to separate the images from a scanned image.
I don't know add code. ' private Bitmap[] ExtractImage(Bitmap source){ //Extract image from image source> } Bitmap[] bitmaps = ExtractImage(bitmap source)'